What are the downsides, if any, of using a toothpaste with a high sodium fluoride concentration?
Assume a male adult, which excludes fluorosis development and pregnancy. What are the downsides, if any, of using a toothpaste with a high sodium fluoride concentration (e.g., sodium fluoride 1.1 per cent, 5,000ppm)?
I Googled the question but I couldn't find any downsides supported by scientific evidence. I could only read some potential upsides.

5000 ppm is prescription strength, which means it must be FDA approved and that means there must be clinical trials.

Studies {1,2,3} report no side effects.
{1}:

No reports of side effects due to the toothpaste or the brushing were noted during the study.

{2}:

No adverse effects of either product were observed during the course of the study.

{3}:

With respect to saliva sampling, no complaints or side effects were reported by any of the test  persons or during any of the toothpaste regimens.


References:

{1} Ekstrand KR, Poulsen JE, Hede B, Twetman S, Qvist V, Ellwood RP. A randomized clinical trial of the anti-caries efficacy of 5,000 compared to 1,450 ppm fluoridated toothpaste on root caries lesions in elderly disabled nursing home residents. Caries Res. 2013;47(5):391-8. doi: 10.1159/000348581. Epub 2013 Apr 9. PMID: 23594784.
{2} Baysan A, Lynch E, Ellwood R, Davies R, Petersson L, Borsboom P. Reversal of primary root caries using dentifrices containing 5,000 and 1,100 ppm fluoride. Caries Res. 2001 Jan-Feb;35(1):41-6. doi: 10.1159/000047429. PMID: 11125195.
{3} Ekstrand KR, Ekstrand ML, Lykkeaa J, Bardow A, Twetman S. Whole-Saliva Fluoride Levels and Saturation Indices in 65+ Elderly during Use of Four Different Toothpaste Regimens. Caries Res. 2015;49(5):489-98. doi: 10.1159/000434730. Epub 2015 Aug 6. PMID: 26278523.

